# How can I make DIV content grow up to a point?

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<div>` which wraps around a table, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
       rows...
    </table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
   Here I have two buttons
</div>
```

Below the table I have two buttons. I want the table to expand and the buttons to move when adding new rows. This works.

The thing that I want is that once the buttons reach the end of the window, scrollbars should appear on the table, so that the buttons will always be visible no matter how small the window is.

This has to be done without Javascript and I'm stuck on the CSS part.

This is my CSS:

```
.container {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%
     overflow-x: auto;
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Is there something I can add to the table to make it work? I can make it display a vertical scrollbar when I make the window smaller - and that is great - but I can't find a solution for the horizontal scrollbar.

So to sum it up, I want horizontal scrollbars when the screen gets small or when the table gets so big that the div with the buttons will be thrown out of the window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without flex. You could do it like this

```css
.buttons {
  height: 40px;
}
.container {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  overflow: scroll;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr><tr><td>Row</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
   Here I have two buttons
</div>
```

Comment: one question, what if I add more stuff above the container div? Do I have to manually add the height of all the other divs above the container in the max-height calculation?

Comment: Yep, think you would have to add that. If you're placing something with a fixed height above this you could change this code a bit to only include the height of the single element above this. See: https://codepen.io/japmul/pen/EvKrZe

You might be better of using flex though, if that's a possibility for you.

Comment: I'll check the Flex solution later, I don't know if I can use it at the moment. But the thing is that this table will be inserted to different sites. So it might be that this container div might have another two divs above it, a navigation bar etc. and I have to achieve this without Javascript and I guess the CSS has to be a little bit dynamic. Do you have any tips? I'm experimenting at the moment to see what works and what not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox on parent element in your case its `body` and set height to `100vh` and then also set `overflow-y: auto` on `container`.

If you also want horizontal scrollbar then you just have to add `white-space: nowrap` on `td` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2102/)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr><tr><td>row</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
   Here I have two buttons
</div>
```